# Robot framework : Pass result from one keyword into another

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I have two keyword **Accept Date** and **Get Date** in robot framework.
**Accept Date** accepts date string & do some work and **Get Date** returns current date string.

I want to pass date string from Get Date to Accept Date without declaring a variable.Some like this in robot framework.

```
Accept Date      Get Date
```

Is it possible to do such thing Robot framework ?

Answer (score 3):

For this to work you'll have to save the result of `Get Date` into a variable and then use that variable as an argument for `Accept Date`.

It is not possible to chain these two calls.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass date string from Get Date to Accept Date without declaring a variable.Some like this in robot framework.

You can't do that, unless you rewrite your keywords. For example, you could modify your `Accept Date` keyword to treat "Get Date" (or perhaps "Today") as a special condition. If it detects that its argument is "Get Date", it can call that keyword and use the result in the rest of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the current date from "Get Date" in to your keyword "Accept Date",
It is necessary to first be sure that your keyword "Get date" returns" the current date but also that "Accept date" is accepting this data. 
Thus, You have to declare both keyword in ***Keywords*** section and use some already existing keywords from Builtin library, string, and so on.
The second solution is to define the role and steps of each keyword in a related python module that you will have to make by yourself.